# How to handle Touch Keypad in Windows Forms on Windows Form Tablet

Tags: vb.net

I am using Windows Forms application and I am not able to auto hide/show the touch keypad thats on the windows 10 Home OS on a tablet. How to handle the touch keypad, Can anyone help me out in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a lot of answers on google for this,

https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&q=vb.net+hide+show+touch+keyboard+windows+10&oq=vb.net+hide+show+touch+keyboard+windows+10&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1296.11486.0.11948.28.27.0.0.0.0.75.1723.27.27.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.20.1290.0..0j0i131k1j0i67k1j0i22i30k1j0i13i30k1j0i8i13i30k1j33i22i29i30k1.TfxlEFKhnRI

Basically you need to create a process for the OSK, load it, and kill it (dependant on if its loaded). Loading and killing the process will show / hide the OSK.